# Type Punning via constexpr union

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2017, type-punning

I am maintaining an old code base, that is using a union of an integer type with a bit-field struct for type-punning.  My compiler is VS2017.  As an example, the code is similar to the following:

```
struct FlagsType
{
    unsigned flag0 : 1;
    unsigned flag1 : 1;
    unsigned flag2 : 1;
};

union FlagsTypeUnion
{
    unsigned  flagsAsInt;
    FlagsType flags;
};

bool isBitSet(unsigned flagNum, FlagsTypeUnion flags)
{
    return ((1u << flagNum) & flags.flagsAsInt);
}
```

This code has a number of undefined behavior issues.  Namely, it is hotly debated whether type punning is defined behavior or not, but on top of that, the implementation of packing bit-fields is implementation-defined.  To address these issues, I would like to add static-assert statements to validate that the VS implementation enables using this type of approach.  However, when I tried to add the following code, I get error *C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant*.

```
union FlagsTypeUnion
{
    unsigned  flagsAsInt;
    FlagsType flags;
    constexpr FlagsTypeUnion(unsigned const f = 0) : flagsAsInt{ f } {}
};

static_assert(FlagsTypeUnion{ 1 }.flags.flag0,
    "The code currently assumes bit-fields are packed from LSB to MSB");
```

Is there any way to add compile-time checks to verify the type-punning and bit-packing code works as the runtime code is assuming?  Unfortunately, this code is spread throughout the code base, so changing the structures isn't really feasible.

Comment: *"it is hotly debated whether type punning is defined behavior or not"* - it is not debated, C++ standard says *"A union holds the value of at most one data member at a time."*

Comment: In new code, the way to approach this is to create an enumerated type with enumerators `flag0 = 0x01`, `flag1 = 0x02`, `flag3 = 0x04`. An object of that type can hold any or all of those values, and checking whether any particular one is present is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (C++20):

```
struct FlagsType
{
    unsigned flag0 : 1;
    unsigned flag1 : 1;
    unsigned flag2 : 1;
    unsigned padding : 32 - 3; // Needed for gcc
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<FlagsType>);

constexpr FlagsType makeFlagsType(bool flag0, bool flag1, bool flag2)
{
    FlagsType res{};

    res.flag0 = flag0;
    res.flag1 = flag1;
    res.flag2 = flag2;
    return res;
}

static_assert(std::bit_cast<unsigned>(makeFlagsType(true, false, false)) == 1);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eG359Gcec)

- clang doesn't support it (yet) though.
- gcc requires to add explicitly the padding bits for the `constexpr` check.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the `bit_cast` method can't be coded without C++20 support.  While this answer will be extremely helpful once we update to VS2019+, the answer to whether this is possible in VS2017 appears to be, "it is not possible to check this at compile-time without a compiler that provides C++20 support".